# Python: How to find the a unique element pattern from 2 arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two `numpy` arrays, `A` and `B`:

```
A = ([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3])
B = ([2, 3, 1, 2])
```

where `B` is a unique pattern within `A`.

I need the output to be all the elements of `A`, which aren't present in `B`.

```
Output = ([1, 2, 3, 1, 3])
```

Comment: They have to be in that order?

Comment: Yes, the order needs to be preserved.

Comment: @mahidhar4 what is the type and range for values in A and B? are these always small ints, or can these be floating point, etc?

Comment: @qarma They are always small ints. My actual values will range from 1 to 6.

Comment: how do you want to handle overlapping matches? e.g. `B = 11011 and A = 11011011`?

Comment: @qarma My A and B arrays are really long, with a length of almost 90k and 10k respectively. So I can safely assume that the patterns won't overlap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest is to use Python's builtins, i.e. string type:

```
A = "123231213"
B = "2312"
result = A.replace(B, "")
```

To efficiently convert `numpy.array` to an from `str`, use these functions:

```
x = numpy.frombuffer("3452353", dtype="|i1")
x
array([51, 52, 53, 50, 51, 53, 51], dtype=int8)
x.tostring()
"3452353"
```

(*) thus mixes up ascii codes (`1 != "1"`), but substring search will work just fine. Your data type should better fit in one char, or you may get a false match.

To sum it up, a quick hack looks like this:

```
A = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3])
B = numpy.array([2, 3, 1, 2])
numpy.fromstring(A.tostring().replace(B.tostring(), ""), dtype=A.dtype)
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 3])
# note, here dtype is some int, I'm relying on the fact that:
# "1 matches 1" is equivalent to "0001 matches 00001"
# this holds as long as values of B are typically non-zero.
#
# this trick can conceptually be used with floating point too,
# but beware of multiple floating point representations of same number
```

In depth explanation:

Assuming size of A and B is arbitrary, [naive approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String%5fsearching%5falgorithm) runs in quadratic time. However better, probabilistic algorithms exit, for example [Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp%5fstring%5fsearch%5falgorithm), which relies on sliding window hash.

Which is the main reason text oriented functions, such as `xxx in str` or `str.replace` or `re` will be much faster than custom `numpy` code.

If you truly need this function to be integrated with numpy, you can always write an extension, but it's not easy :)

Comment: What if A contains the number `23`? This will only work for single digit numbers.

Comment: Can't you use set operations on numpy arrays (like intersect)? IMHO that would be the operation to use if available.

Comment: @Nicoretti thing is OP wants to find arbitrary length *sequence*, not a set.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary indeed, OP only uses small ints, he's safe. For larger alphabet, 4-byte int representation can be used. in that case representation must be large enough to always have a leading zero, thus 2-byte for values up to 256, 4-byte for values up to 256**3, 8-byte for values up to 256**7, etc. and there shouldn't be too many zeros, in which case an offset can be used.

Comment: This works, as long as I'm converting. I'm still worried about the conversion performance, since my 2 arrays might increase in size at a future time. But I'll try it out.

Comment: @Nicoretti Yes, I was hoping that there was a way to do this using only numpy methods, but I'm not able to find any.

Comment: @mahidhar4 numpy's built-in conversion is pretty quick. where do you get your arrays from? are those computed in numpy or do you load those from a text file? in the latter case you can try to use python's builtins directly on file data without numpy.

Comment: @qarma They are computed in numpy. Your solution should work though. I should be able to deal with performance with the algorithm itself. Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: @mahidhar4 what about the numphy interstect1d function? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html